# php htmlspecialchars_decode() issue

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I have a slight issue. I need to get `htmlspecialchars_decode` to run immediately before before the `$CmdExe = 'nircmd` runs as it is interfering as it wont execute properly. So basically I am needing the `$PlayMovie` to already have a decoded value before proceeding. How can I make this work? I use php desktop and nircmd executes functions on the PC as needed. It works great until a name has a special char in the database such as `&#039;`. All special chars where put into the database using `htmlspecialchars`. nircmd is still seeing the value undecoded so I need these decoded before it hits this line. Or is it decoded already? I ask because when I test the `$PlayMovie` variable without encoded values it works fine. Unusual question I know however my php skills are still in the beginner stage. Much appreciated in advance.

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE id = '$RecID'");

while($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

$MovieFile = $row["FileName"];

$PlayMovie = htmlspecialchars_decode($MovieFile);

//NEEDS TO BE DECODED BEFORE THIS LINE
$CmdExe = 'nircmd.exe shexec "open" "'. $MovieHostDrive . $PlayMovie .'"';

exec($CmdExe);

}
```

Upon further testing when I do a `str_replace` it works. So is `htmlspecialchars_decode` not working?

```
 //This Works
 $PlayMovie = str_replace("&#039;", "'", $MovieFile);

//This doesn't
$PlayMovie = htmlspecialchars_decode($MovieFile);
```

Comment: Regardless of the filename having quotes which you should of stripped before storing, you should be using http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process that you are using, with inserting the database output into a php declaration, you need to escape the qoute until it reaches. it would be strange that the substitue string will work in the declaration since the other parts after the single quote would go into the php zone and cause some sort of syntax error. But if you need to do that code above, you would escape it with a backslash character \ as the single quote is converted.

so change this:

```
      $PlayMovie = str_replace("&#039;", "'", $MovieFile)
```

to this:

```
       $PlayMovie = str_replace("&#039;", "\'", $MovieFile);
```

then this line will work, because the single quote is escaped in php, but the modifyer will be removed when php executes the varible. just like html code.

```
     $CmdExe = 'nircmd.exe shexec "open" "'. $MovieHostDrive . $PlayMovie .'"';
```

Comment: it has to be without the " \ " as nircmd is executing that string not php. PHP just starts nircmd and then nircmd takes over and launches the rest.

Comment: the escaped string would get removed in the built in command exec() , but one thing makes me wonder is why are you not using escapeshellarg()

Comment: everything beyond nircmd.exe is NOT php related. It is for nircmd only. PHP Desktop has things you can do that you cannot traditional do in plain old php. Take a look at it. Its pretty fascinating.

Comment: yes but its in php until it is executed with the execute command, so someone could inject .dir  .' in it and reveal the directory (or any other line command that works on the os like ls in linux). That is why adding the escape characters with escapeshellarg before storing and the decode is transparent (no decode routine needed).

Comment: Its PHP Desktop. It runs locally. Its nowhere near the internet or public. It doesn't matter if the directory is exposed as its the users personal directory (mine in this instance). It runs as a desktop application

Comment: I would still use escapeshellarg just because its good practices.